# PROC OLAP - leaving out nway but including other aggregations

Tags: sas, olap, cube

I'm trying to optimise the build time of a large cube. I am using SAS OCS. I have looked at the ARM logs and it would seem that the NWAY aggregation is never used (or hasn't been for the last 2 months). I am therefore confident I can leave out the default nway aggregation. I would however like to leave in a handful of the other aggregations.

I have deleted the nway creation from the code directly and included 'no_nway' as an option on the proc olap statement, whilst leaving the other aggregations in place. However, I am getting these error messages:

```
ERROR: A failure occurred as a result of a problem in creating cube aggregations.

ERROR: A problem was encountered during the aggregation phase of cube building.
```

Do I need to leave the nway aggreagtion in place if I am going to create other aggregations?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? `PROC OLAP` is one of the most complicated SAS procedures I've ever used (hence the wizard).

Comment: The code is horrendously long as there are a number of dimensions, levels and over 100 aggregations, but I see how more information is probably needed to get any help. I think it's down to some undesired data, as I have spotted a couple of errors prior to this saying that data values have not found. This however is not an issue if I include the nway aggregation. I am now trying it on a new set of data. Thank you.